# How to add third-party framework like SVProgressHUD into theos project

Tags: ios, reverse-engineering, theos, svprogresshud

I would like to use SVProgressHUD (no matter .a or .framework) in my theos reverse engineering Project.

I tried to put headers in /opt/theos/inlcude
and put .framework file in /op/theos/lib

and add EXTRA_FRAMEWORK += SVProgressHUD in makefile file.

it can compile without issues.
but it somehow does not work.

any idea?

Comment: Found any info on this?